# Compact manifold without boundary is boundary of another manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Is it true, that a compact (topological?) manifold without boundary is a boundary of another compact manifold? Intuitively it looks like for most manifolds there must be some relation similar to $\mathbb{S}^n=\partial D^{n+1}$.

It looks like a very trivial question, though I can not find any reference.

Thanks.